# Accessing child nodes of a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a div using the following code...

```
var bannerBox = document.createElement("div");
bannerBox.id = "bannerBox";
```

...and a second div as follows...

```
var bannerAd = document.createElement("div");
bannerAd.className = "bannerAd";
```

The above divs have been created in one function. Now in another function I tried to access the first div as follows...

```
var allAds = document.getElementById("bannerBox").childNodes;
```

...but it produces this error:
**uncaught error cannot read property childnodes of null**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually put the `bannerBox` div in the document, by passing it into `appendChild` or `insertBefore` on some element that's in the document (such as `document.body`):

```
document.body.appendChild(bannerBox);
```

(But it can be any element in the document, doesn't have to be `body`.)

Once it's in the document, you can retrieve it by `id` the way you've shown.

And of course (this isn't the problem you're having but it could be the *next* problem), for `bannerBox` to have any child nodes (e.g., for `childNodes` not to be an empty `NodeList`), you need to put something in it. From your variable names, I'm thinking probably you'd want to put `bannerAd` in it, for instance:

```
bannerBox.appendChild(bannerAd);
```

Comment: i used this 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(bannerBox);
but it produces error
cannot call method appendchild of undefined

Comment: @AmberAslam: If you used that from code within the `head` of the document, that could be why (there's no `body` yet). Moving the `script` tag containing the code *into* the `body` tag should sort it.